# How to kill a pipeline once some output has occurred

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to run this:

```
./configure | grep GNU
```

but the configure script hangs after it has output the lines I'm grepping, waiting for user input (which I'm not going to provide here). 
Is there a way I can kill the pipeline once output from grep has occurred?

Comment: Nope. I just get the line I'm looking for repeated to stdout until I kill it via Ctrl+C.

Comment: Are you sure that `./configure` is expecting some input? I have never seen that. What project does this `./configure` script come from?

Comment: Have you tried `tee`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect “GNU” to appear in the output only once, try

```
./configure | { grep -m1 GNU; pkill configure;}
```

so the `grep` exits after finding one match. 
More generally, if you expect “GNU” to appear *N* times,
use `-mN`.

Answer (score 0):

If configure is looking for input, you'll have to provide it some input, or rework it to skip that input step.